# ElasticSearch in e-commerce: multiple categories for a product

Tags: elasticsearch, e-commerce, categories

How do you index products like that in ElasticSearch? We've separated all documents based on the attributes (colour, brand, size, whatever users input), but all of them belong to a set of categories. May be one, may be 15.

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 123456
                [product_name] => Shirt 1
                [filter_name] => Colour
                [filter_value] => Blue
                [product_parent_id] => 111111
                [product_has_discount] => 0
                [product_price] => 19.99
                [product_stock] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 123457
                [product_name] => Shirt 1
                [filter_name] => Colour
                [filter_value] => Red
                [product_parent_id] => 111111
                [product_has_discount] => 0
                [product_price] => 19.99
                [product_stock] => 1
            )
```

How would we tag categories into this? Would it be so simple as saying

```
        [product_categories] => ;4750;4834;4835;4836;
```

And then querying ElasticSearch with `match against category` with the value `;4836;`? Is that possible? Recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `product_categories` as integer in your mapping and pass in the category values as array like

```
 [product_categories] => array(4750,4834,4835,4836)
```

**EDIT**: You read more about mapping [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html). A more specific to mapping an [array type](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-array-type.html).

Once your data is indexed like that you can query, filter, aggregate on the field `product_categories` easily in all combinations.

for example to match products in category 4750 or 4750:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "terms": {
            "product_categories": [
                4750,
                4750
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Is there documentation somewhere for this? I've searched high and low, but to no avail.

Comment: Elasticsearch has a very nice documentation at http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html. I have edited the answer to include links to mapping and array mapping.

Comment: I was trying to find concrete examples, looking for 'multivalue field', or 'multifield'. Did find something on duplicate keys, that should be passed as arrays, but would actually be overwritten each time. I have a hard time accepting ES in my life, although I really love the thing. :P

Comment: Concrete examples may not be there but the documentation covers most areas need to design a solution. If you can present a use case or a requirement scenario you will get a better direction. As far as i understand, for an e-commerce like scenario, elasticsearch is a fantastic tool which gives you lots of features out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've gotten from this too, but none of the videos I watched, answers I found, tutorials I checked went into how to actually format your data. We're new to this entire thing, and ES isn't very newbie friendly so to say.

Comment: I would disagree on your last point :). I have use raw Lucene, Solr and Elasticsearch. Among them I found elasticsearch most easy to learn/adopt (may be helped by the fact that i have use lucene and solr earlier). For start install a plugin like https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf which will give you a nice interface to play around and give you more confidence about the elasticsearch (doing curl request on vi is difficult specially with big json inputs). Create an index - create a mapping you are sort of ready to go

Comment: Apparently I've auto-moved this convo to a chat.  [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76442/discussion-between-mave-and-prabin-meitei).

Comment: How to handle similar approach but with multiple categories that have hierarchy levels, I mean categories like in stadard ecoomerce app, that one sublevel of categories is present in current selected category???

Comment: You can define all sub-categories in different field. Eg. Category1: shirt, category2: red, category3: arrow etc. The hierarchy level can be implemented using aggregation inside aggregation (pivot aggregation).  It's similar to a sql query of group by (category1,category2,category3)